# Presentation doesn't automatically start in fullscreen and shows a flickering?

Tags: beamer

I wrote my thesis presentation using beamer package. In the below code you can see the full preamble.

I think there is something wrong with it: it doesn't start in **fullscreen mode** automatically and when I use PDF Exchange Viewer (my favorite viewer) there is a **flickering** when changing the frame.

Is there something I can do to "enable" the presentation mode?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% packages
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{textpos}

% settings
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\graphicspath{{./images/}}

% titlepage
% ...

% document includes
\begin{document}
    % ...
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

As you already have the `hyperref` package loaded (if I remember correct, this package is already loaded when you use `beamer`) you just need to add in your preamble this line

```
\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=FullScreen}
```

and that should do the work for the full screen mode. For the flickering however it is probably linked to your viewer rather than to `beamer`.

Comment: I think there is a problem with PDF Exchange, even with that option my PDF opens normally (i.e. not in fullscreen). I'm going to try Sumatra, thanks.